# Editing PHP5.INI file on Godaddy Linux Hosting

Tags: php

I need to edit the PHP INI file my Godaddy Linux Hosting Account.

I have located the file using SSH, I am able to download it but when I upload the edited file, I get Permission Denied.

I googled it out but can't find a solution. Found a blog 9 months old whining about exactly the same problem but no answers.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Godaddy?

Comment: if you're using SSH start with a shell and an editor in the shell like `vi` or similar. Anyway, this website is no Godaddy support forum, so you must have been misguided to post your question here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom php.ini file and upload it to the root of your shared hosting account along with the rest of your website content.  This will not be located at /etc/php.ini.

Comment: sir...even i have a similar kind of problem that in my local server session is working properly but when i host it on live server i.e godaddy linux server sessions are totally ignored..!! is it mandatory to manually script php.ini file or the sessions will be taken by server side..??